# Ppseudorandom scalar on grid points

Tags: python

I am trying to generate pseudorandom scalar on a defined grid but this is showing only one value. Kindly help!

```
import numpy as np
from random import randrange
n=10
a=np.zeros((n,n), dtype=complex).reshape(n,n)
for i in np.arange(0.01,0.03,n):
    for j in np.arange(0.01,0.02,n):
        a[i,j]=randrange(0,1,10)
        print a
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `np.arange(0.01, 0.03, 10)` just produces `array([ 0.01])`; what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There are two major issues.

### The index is always 0

You iterate over `np.arange(0.01,0.03,n)`. Since the step width `n = 10` is larger than your range `0.03 - 0.01`, you only get one value:

```py
print np.arange(0.01,0.03,n)
```

Output:

```
[ 0.01]
```

Rounded towards an integer this index is `0`, so you only assign the top left entry of the array `a`.

### The assigned value is always 0

Same problem with `randrange(0,1,10)`: You choose a random number from 0 to 1 with step width 10, which always yields the only possible value 0.

---

When debugging such algorithms, try breaking it down to the smallest chunks possible and print them to the command line to check whether they do what you expect them to do.

Comment: But I cannot use random() since it takes only one argument. What I am trying to accomplish here is on each point of the grid, I have a pseudorandom scalar.

Comment: ```np.random.rand()``` should be what you are looking for. (uniform distribution form 0 to 1)